# how to find the implementation of C getchar() on my system (Mac OS)?

Tags: c

I understand that `int getchar(void)` is a C library function.

How can I find its implementation on my current Mac OS? FYI, using 'man getchar` from Terminal I got:

```
GETC(3)                  BSD Library Functions Manual                  GETC(3)

NAME
     fgetc, getc, getc_unlocked, getchar, getchar_unlocked, getw -- get next character or word from input stream

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdio.h>

     int
     fgetc(FILE *stream);

     int
     getc(FILE *stream);

     int
     getc_unlocked(FILE *stream);

     int
     getchar(void);

     int
     getchar_unlocked(void);

     int
     getw(FILE *stream);
```

Comment: not open source, but you can refer to the nearest similar code in *BSD(freebsd, net, dragonfly etc)

Comment: @Mihir - in fact, Apple provides parts of their system as open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take a look at implementation from Apple, you have to look inside theirs Open Source section:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.250.1/stdio/FreeBSD/getchar.c.auto.html

You can find all the Open Sourced codes at: opensource.apple.com

Unless, by implementation we mean:

```
> nm /usr/lib/libcupscgi.dylib | grep "getchar"
U _getchar
```